# Postgres SQL Calculated Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL and PostGres newbie alert. I'm trying to put together a simple query which takes the result of a join of two tables (staging.customers and prod.policies), then before inserting the result into a third table (prod.result), lets me transoform the values with simple functions/expressions.

I'm hoping if I can get this simple synthetic example working, it will fall into place for me.

I have the following:

```sql
1  UPDATE prod.result
2 
3  SET customerid  = cust.customerid
4    ,first      = cust.first
5    ,last       = cust.last
6    ,age        = cust.age
7    ,policytype = pol.policytype
8   
9  FROM staging.customers cust
10      JOIN prod.policies pol
11      ON cust.customerid = pol.customerid;
12  
13 INSERT INTO prod.result(
14      customerid
15      ,first
16      ,last
17      ,age 
18      ,policytype
19  )
20 SELECT   cust.customerid
21      ,cust.first
22      ,cust.last
23      ,cust.age
24      ,pol.policytype
25      
26 FROM staging.customers cust
27  JOIN prod.policies pol
28  ON cust.customerid = pol.customerid;
```

Schemas:

```
staging.customers
 - customerid: integer
 - first: varchar(255)
 - last: varchar(255)
 - age: integer

prod.policies
 - customerid: integer
 - policynumber: varchar(255)
 - policytype: varchar(255)

prod.result
 - customerid: integer
 - first: varchar(255)
 - last: varchar(255)
 - age: integer
 - policytype: varchar(255)
```

I had thought that I could use the SET block beginning on line 1 and ending on line 7 to do things like:

```
6    ,age        = (cust.age + 5)
```

I don't get any errors and values are inserted, but the value of age is not increased by 5 when I:

```
SELECT * FROM prod.result;
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? All I want is a way to manipulate the results of a join before writing the results into another table. Would really appreciate any assistance!

Comment: A normal SQL statement does not have line numbers (it is not COBOL....!)

Comment: 1) *...  and values are inserted* is confusing. If you are talking about the UPDATE then the values are updated. Do you get an UPDATE count? 2) There is no WHERE for the UPDATE so all the rows will be updated in some unknown order. 3) It should a be `age = age + (cust.age + 5)`. This assumes `cust.age` = `prod.result.age`. Otherwise  `age = age + 5`.

Comment: You didn't specify which rows of `prod.result` are supposed to be updated with values from which rows in the source combination of `staging.customers` and `prod.policies`. Even if some rows are affected, it's not possible to determine which ones.

Comment: Not reproduceable , because the value of ages gets updated to value+5, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/oZuy3oOL

Comment: BTW: Never store `age` in a database. It is much smarter to store `birthdate`, so you can calculate the age of someone.

Comment: Coffee just kicked in. This `age = age + (cust.age + 5)` is not correct if `cust.age = prod.result.age`. It would be the simple case `age = age + 5`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: You need -er coffee.... 

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing what `update` and `insert` do. If you start with a brand new, empty `prod.result` table, then run your update, it does absolutely nothing because there's nothing to [`update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html). Then the insert only writes what's currently in `staging.customers` and `prod.policies`.

This:

> takes the result of a join of two tables (staging.customers and prod.policies), then before inserting the result into a third table (prod.result), lets me transoform the values with simple functions/expressions

all can be done in a single [`insert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). You can change what you're reading from the source tables on the fly, before writing to your `result`, right in the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO prod.result(--inserting the result into a third table (prod.result)
      customerid
      ,first
      ,last
      ,age 
      ,policytype
  )
 SELECT   cust.customerid
      ,cust.first
      ,cust.last
      ,cust.age + 5  --"lets me transoform the values with simple functions/expressions"
      ,pol.policytype

 FROM staging.customers cust --"takes the result of a join of two tables (staging.customers and prod.policies)"
  JOIN prod.policies pol
  ON cust.customerid = pol.customerid;
```

If you want to pre-populate `result` with the rows from `staging.customers` and `prod.policies` and then change them somehow, run the `insert` first, and then the `update` after that, entirely without the `from` if you only bump values up or down, without the need to reference a row from any other row or table:

```
UPDATE prod.result
  SET age        = age + 5 --this is applied to `age` in every row
      --all other columns remain unchanged
;
```

If your script has a `create` statement for the `result` table right before all this, you can actually merge the creation, read, transformation and write all into one [`create table as select`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) statement.